# Mono performance issue when passing arguments from bash file

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I've just came across this tremendously weird behavior of Mono when executing C# program directly from command line and as a shell script. Minimal version of the program basically reads the input file and does something with it. I've noticed a huge performance difference between executing the program from command line such as:

```
mono program.exe file.txt
```

The task is done within a seconds.

However, if I create a shell script execute.sh and fill it with

```
#!/bin/bash
mono program.exe $1
```

the successive execution of ./execute.sh file.txt takes up to 10 minutes. I just can wrap my head around this. Has anyone come across similar issue? Do you have an idea what might be wrong? The version of mono I'm using is 3.10 on Fedora 16. The program is compiled for .NET 4 Client version framework. I've also tested it under mas os and 3.6 mono and it seems to be OK there. So perhaps something might be wrong with installation of mono?

The minimalistic code looks like this:

```
Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var a = ReadMyFile.Read(args[0]);
Console.WriteLine("Structure read in {0}", w.Elapsed.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it on ubuntu 14.04 and I have no such problem.

By the way, there is no ReadMyFile.Read, you might want to add the exact code you used.

Comment: Sure there is no such method. Actually it is a pretty complex code which reads the data and parses and I don't want to bother people by this. I think it is a mono to blame. But don't know why

Comment: If you don't provide a testcase which can be tested, then your "bug report", which should be actually done on the bugtracker of mono, is useless.